# Ajax Post Type will not send data to php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following form for users to reset their password it is within the file forgotten.php in the root directory.

```
<form id="pass_form" action="" method="post" name="pass_form">
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="blank" name="name" id="name" value="Trader Username" data-default="Trader Username" data-message="Please enter your username..."> *<br>
  <input class="sub-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like to post the username to inc/sendreset.php so I have the following Ajax in js/scripts.js

```
    $("#pass_form").validator({
    offset: [0, 354],
    position: 'center left',
    messageClass: 'conerror'
}).submit(function(e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var form = $(this);
        var serdata = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendreset",
            data: serdata,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                log('inside ajax sendreset', this, arguments);
                $('#pass_form').fadeOut(400,function(){
                    if (html=="0") {

                    } else {
                        $('#pass_form').html('<p>The password reset instructions have been sent. Please check your email.</p>');
                    }
                    $('#pass_form').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                log('error inside ajax sendreset', this, arguments);
            }
        });
        //$('#pass_form').fadeOut(400);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However it does not seem to post the username into the file. The inc/sendreset.php is as follows

```
<?php
        require_once('./library.php');
        require_once('./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

        $Trader = new CompanyTrader();

        $resetdata = $Trader->resetTrader($_POST['name']);
        print_arr($resetdata);

        //more php which isn't relevant
?>
```

I know the file inc/sendreset.php works as when I the file to use $_GET['name'] and i use inc/sendreset.php?name=username the array is returned for the relevant user. It does not work from forgotten.php using Ajax though. Please help!

Comment: Why do you assign url = "sendreset" instead of to "inc/sendreset.php"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i really think this is wrong:

```
url: "sendreset",
```

try with an relative or absolute url like `http://mysite.com`

Comment: the reason I didnt put in the absolute URL was because I had URL ReWrite in my htacces but had somehow deleted the rule for inc/sendreset.php. Your comments drew my attention to this. Thanks.