# Ajax Query will not send post value to php

Tags: php, ajax

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to figure out where the problem in my code is.

I have a table with a radio button in php I need to get the ID of this button and use it in a sql query. I have used ajax to get the ID and can successfully alert the value I need, however the problem is I can not seem to get the ID value to post to the $_POST['id']; in PHP. It just stays blank. The code is all on the same page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('table tr').click(function()
        {
                $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
                var temp = parseInt($(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr("id"), 10);
                ++temp;
                $.post(window.location, { 'IDENT': temp });

                 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location,
                data: {IDENT: temp},

                });

        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my Javascript retrieving the value in which I can alert(temp) and see the desired result. However echo $_POST['IDENT']; stays empty.

Sorry if this an obvious question I am fairly new to both PHP and Javascript

Comment: where is the location of `php` page? or is it in current page? let me know

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047293/ajax-post-type-will-not-send-data-to-php-page this will help you is this problem is similar to you

Comment: your `temp` var is empty.

Comment: The php is in the current page, should it be above or below the JS or doesn't it matter? The Temp var contains the required value which is given when the user clicks the radiobutton

Comment: why are you using $.post and $.ajax both ?

Comment: where are you expecting the result on the same page? See in console in firefox,

Comment: I attempted both methods but neither of them seem to work

Comment: POST http://lawson/~liamm4/Ass1-liamm4/admin/master_page_usercont.php 
200 OK   10ms  This is shown in the consol when the radio button is clicked.

Comment: missing )var temp = parseInt($(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr("id"), 10);
                ++temp; at this end

Comment: Missing bracket? I think it is correct otherwise that part would not provide a correct alert value

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(window.location, { 'IDENT': temp });   //<-----   IDENT: temp

             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.location,
            data: {IDENT: temp},    //<-----   del comma

            });
```